# Expected value of a $X^a$

Tags: probability, lebesgue-integral, expected-value

Suppose that $X$ is a positive random variable and $a<0$. Is it true that:

$$E[X^a]\leq E[X]^a$$

This seems right to me and I know that this inequality holds for the case that $X=1_B$ (indicator function) where $0<P(B)<1$. However, I can't seem to prove the general case.

I'll appreciate hints!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the example $X=1_B$ because $X^{a}$ is undefined on $B^{c}$.

The reverse inequality is true. The function $f(x)=x^{a}$ is a convex function on $(0,\infty)$ and Jensen's inequality shows that $(EX)^{a} \leq E(X^{a})$. The inequality is strict except when $X$ is a constant.